# What preposition should follow the adjective “parallel”?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

When using the word *parallel* in communicating the state of being in a relationship between one line and another, what is the correct word to follow *parallel*?

1. parallel *to*
2. parallel *with*

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible. COCA has 1964 citations for 'parallel to' and 398 for 'parallel with'.